# Using css3 for background of website

Tags: css, background, grid, gradient

I want to get exactly this result with CSS3 and HTML5 texhnologies using no images.

here is HTML

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="lines"></div>
```

and CSS

```
body {
    background: #45484d;
    z-index:-5;
}

#lines {
      background-size: 20px 20px;    
    background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #fff 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 7px),-webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, #fff, #fff 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 7px);
    background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #fff 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 7px),-moz-repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, #fff, #fff 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 7px);
    background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #fff 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 7px),-o-repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, #fff, #fff 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 7px);
    background-image:repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #fff 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 7px),repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, #fff, #fff 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 7px);
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    opacity:0.14;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-4;
}

#overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-3;
}
```

I kinda get some piece of reuslt on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tt13/BA8Wk/2/

But can't figure out what to do else. Can anyone help me to achieve this result?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BrlY.jpg

Comment: give `#lines` a greater z-index value than `#overlay`, i.e make it `-2` and then add radial CSS3 gradient to `#overlay`
Example : http://jsbin.com/opiked/1/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- dabblet: http://dabblet.com/gist/4649123
- jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W4LpR/6/ (try opening the results in a larger window)

HTML

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="lines"></div>
<div id="lines2"></div>
```

CSS

```css
body {
    background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(center, circle closest-corner, #636363 0%, #27282B 100%);
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center, circle closest-corner, #636363 0%, #27282B 100%);
    background-image: -o-radial-gradient(center, circle closest-corner, #636363 0%, #27282B 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 447, color-stop(0, #636363), color-stop(1, #27282B));
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, circle closest-corner, #636363 0%, #27282B 100%);
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at center, #636363 0%, #27282B 100%);
    z-index:-5;
}

#lines {
      background-size: 20px 20px;    
    background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #fff 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 20px),-webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, #fff, #fff 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 20px);
    background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #fff 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 20px),-moz-repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, #fff, #fff 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 20px);
    background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #fff 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 20px),-o-repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, #fff, #fff 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 20px);
    background-image:repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #fff 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 20px),repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, #fff, #fff 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 20px);
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    opacity:0.14;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-4;
}

#lines2 {
      background-size: 100px 100px;    
    background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #fff 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100px),-webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, #fff, #fff 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100px);
    background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #fff 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100px),-moz-repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, #fff, #fff 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100px);
    background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #fff 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100px),-o-repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, #fff, #fff 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100px);
    background-image:repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #fff 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100px),repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, #fff, #fff 2px, transparent 2px, transparent 100px);
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    opacity:0.14;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-3;
}

#overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-2;
}
```

Comment: I can't see radial gradient on firefox

Comment: @megatron Which version of firefox are you using? I can see the gradient clearly on firefox.

Comment: @megatron I use 17.0.1 and can still see the gradient.

Comment: please make it cross-browser

Comment: @megatron It's a problem with jsfiddle. Try copy and paste the code and run it on your local hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

My try on this (only -webkit rules (Chrome) for demo):

```
background-size: 100px 100px;    

background-image:
   repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #999, transparent 2px, transparent 20px),
   repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 100px),
   repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #999, transparent 2px, transparent 20px),
   repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #fff 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 100px);
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dXyHQ/))

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dXyHQ/1/)'s one with added stripes:

```
background-size:4px 4px; 
background-image: 
  repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 1px, #333 2px, transparent 3px);
```

Comment: I can't see radial gradient on firefox

Comment: just add the same rules with the `-moz-` prefix